# Remove all occurrences of a particular key from a JSON response in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON string from which I want to eliminate all the occurrences of a given key.

JSON I have:

```
string requstBody =       
{
              "payLoad": [
                {
                  "BaseVersionId_": 9,
                  "VersionId_": 10,              
                  "AssetCollateralLink": [
                    {
                      "AssetId": 137,
                      "BaseVersionId_": 9,
                      "VersionId_": 10
                    },
                    {
                      "AssetId": 136,
                      "BaseVersionId_": 0,
                      "VersionId_": 1
                    }
                  ],
                  "CollateralProvider": [],
                  "AdvCollateralAllocation": [
                    {
                      "LinkId": 91,
                      "IsDeleted_": false,
                      "BaseVersionId_": 1,
                      "VersionId_": 2
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
```

I want to eliminate keys "BaseVersionID_" and "VersionId_" as follows:

```
  string requstBody =  
{
              "payLoad": [
                {
                  "AssetCollateralLink": [
                    {
                      "AssetId": 137
                    },
                    {
                      "AssetId": 136
                    }
                  ],
                  "CollateralProvider": [],
                  "AdvCollateralAllocation": [
                    {
                      "LinkId": 91,
                      "IsDeleted_": false
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
```

I used JObject.Remove(); as follows

```
JObject sampleObj1 = new JObject();
sampleObj1 = JsonHelper.JsonParse(requestBody);
sampleObj1.Remove("BaseVersionId_");
```

but able to remove the keys under payLoad Hierarchy only.
How do I remove all the occurrences of the Key.

Comment: Your provided Json payload is not in correct format. Provide the correct one as per Json

Comment: @Sh.Imran Fixed. Thank you

Comment: Since JObject is a IEnumerable, you can use `foreach` though the `sampleObj1` and remove ?

Answer (score 0):

The required properties can be removed from the `Json`, simply with Linq:

```
var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(requestBody);
jsonObj.SelectToken("payLoad[0]").SelectToken("AdvCollateralAllocation")
                .Select(jt => (JObject)jt)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(r =>
                    r
                    .Properties()
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(e =>
                    {
                        if (e.Name == "BaseVersionId_" || e.Name == "VersionId_")
                            e.Remove();
                    }));
```

The resultant `jsonObj` will be without the `BaseVersionId_` and `VersionId_` names as well as their values.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use JsonPath as such:

```
var toRemove =  jsonObject
                .SelectTokens("$.payLoad.[*].AssetCollateralLink.[*]..BaseVersionId_")
                .Concat(stuff.SelectTokens("$.payLoad.[*].AssetCollateralLink.[*]..VersionId_"))
                .Concat(stuff.SelectTokens("$.payLoad.[*].AdvCollateralAllocation.[*]..VersionId_"))
                .Concat(stuff.SelectTokens("$.payLoad.[*].AdvCollateralAllocation.[*]..BaseVersionId_"))
                .ToList();

for (int i = toRemove.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    toRemove[i].Parent?.Remove();
}
```